# How to move my cursor to the last record in MySQL using Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using MySQLdb library to connect to MySQL within my Python script.

(Ref: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html ).

I would like to learn if there is a way to jump to the last record in a resultset using Python?
In other words, I would like to move my cursor to the last record in the resultset.

Comment: It seems not many people understand this question but this is totally valid concern for people who know `CURSOR` in SQL.  Unfortunately most of `cursor` implementations in Python are the client side cursor (aka fake cursor).   It doesn't issue `DECLARE CURSOR`, hence no support of `MOVE`.  The only server side implementation I'm aware of is the named cursor of `psycopg2` for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your question is weird. Why would you want to do that?

You could keep reading records from the cursor until it is the last. But you'd have to try reading past it to know it is the last one, you can't know before reading it.

Another idea is to make a reversed query. Use `ORDER BY` to reverse the result order and the last will come first.

Or if you know the number of records, you could use `OFFSET` to return only the last one. You could issue a `COUNT` query first to know the number, and then use this number on `OFFSET`.

Comment: And don't forget to use `LIMIT` so that you only fetch the record you are interested in and not the whole table.

Comment: I don't think the first two solutions would be efficient on large databases. The third solution (OFFSET) is interesting, that's probably what I'm looking for since Python's MySQL API does not provide functions such as afterLast(), beforeFirst() which are pretty common in some other programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel the query is not too hard on the db, and there is enough memory on the machine, you could store the result set in a list, and just grab the last object from the list:

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='',user='',passwd='')
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute('show databases') # or whatever query
last_result = [x[0] for x in curs.fetchall()][-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

curs.execute("SELECT ghfhgf")

return an int with the number of records.

To move from one records to another x steps

curs.scroll(x)

So

curs.scroll(curs.execute("SELECT hgffg"))

Can work for you.